# Login Page Issue

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, admin

Could somebody edit this code so I can login without username and password as I'm locked out of my website even though I'm the admin.

```
#
$data['PageName']='MEMBER LOGIN'; $data['PageFile']='login';

#
include('../config.htm');

#
if(!$_SESSION['attempts'])$_SESSION['attempts']=0;

#
if($post['send']){ if($_SESSION['attempts']

    }elseif(!is_member_active($post['username'])){
            $data['Error']='This member was not found in the system. Or is inactive, banned or closed.';
    }elseif(!is_member_found($post['username'], md5($post['password']))){
       $data['Error']='Your have entered a wrong username or password.';
    }else{
        unset($_SESSION['attempts']);

        $_SESSION['uid']=get_member_id($post['username'], md5($post['password']));
        $_SESSION['login']=true;
        set_last_access($post['username']);
        save_remote_ip((int)$_SESSION['uid'], $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
        if($data['UseTuringNumber'])unset($_SESSION['turing']);
        header("Location:{$data['Host']}/members/index.htm");
        echo('ACCESS DENIED.');
        exit;
    }
    (int)$_SESSION['attempts']++;
}else{ if($data['UseTuringNumber'])unset($_SESSION['turing']); unset($_SESSION['attempts']); $data['CantLogin']=true; } } $data['attempts']=$_SESSION['attempts'];

#
if($data['UseTuringNumber'])$_SESSION['turing']=gencode();

#
display('members');

#
?>
```

Comment: Um.. what? If you have access to the code, there's a good chance you've got access to the DB. Can't you just update your username and password? Though, your code doesn't even look like valid PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This code would log you every time, doesn't matter what password you used.

```
#
$data['PageName']='MEMBER LOGIN'; $data['PageFile']='login';

#
include('../config.htm');

#
if(!$_SESSION['attempts'])$_SESSION['attempts']=0;

#
if($post['send']){ if($_SESSION['attempts']

    }elseif(!is_member_active($post['username'])){
            $data['Error']='This member was not found in the system. Or is inactive, banned or closed.';
    }elseif(false){
       $data['Error']='Your have entered a wrong username or password.';
    }else{
        unset($_SESSION['attempts']);

        $_SESSION['uid']=get_member_id($post['username'], md5($post['password']));
        $_SESSION['login']=true;
        set_last_access($post['username']);
        save_remote_ip((int)$_SESSION['uid'], $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
        if($data['UseTuringNumber'])unset($_SESSION['turing']);
        header("Location:{$data['Host']}/members/index.htm");
        echo('ACCESS DENIED.');
        exit;
    }
    (int)$_SESSION['attempts']++;
}else{ if($data['UseTuringNumber'])unset($_SESSION['turing']); unset($_SESSION['attempts']); $data['CantLogin']=true; } } $data['attempts']=$_SESSION['attempts'];

#
if($data['UseTuringNumber'])$_SESSION['turing']=gencode();

#
display('members');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create an exception before your `if` for your IP using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

So if the computer accessing your website have an IP matching your you could automatically log him in?